# Registration form validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to validate this form ignoring default values of input fields. I tried all possible ways with jQuery validate plugin. It's hard to understand how to use it, since I'm a beginner to JS.

My form looks like that

```
<?php
require "core/code/includes/db.php";
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Baza ilə əlaqədə problem var: %s\n Xahiş edirik administrator ilə əlaqə yaradasınız: mail@tural.us", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
?>
<form id="reg" method="post" action="core/code/functions/signup.php" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<table width="270px" style="clear:both">
<tr>
<td class="numbers" rowspan="3">
1
</td>
<td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px">
Əsas məlumatlar 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td ><input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="fname" value="Adınız"  /></td>
  <td ><input  class="part1 default required"  type="text" name="mname"  value="Atanızın adı"/></td>
 <td ><input  class="part1 default" type="text" name="lname"  value="Soyadınız" /></td>
</tr>
...

...
<input class="button button-gray"  type="submit" value="Tamam" name="submit"/>
</p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/code/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="core/code/js/mask.js"></script>
<script src="core/code/js/reg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/code/js/acompl.js"></script>
```

And reg.js

```
var defaultValues = {
    'fname': 'Adınız',
    'mname': 'Atanızın adı',
    'lname': 'Soyadınız',
    'phone': 'Telefon',
    'email': 'Email',
    'pwd':'Şifrə',
    'region':'Rayon',
    'school':'Məktəb',
    'login':'Istifadəçi adı',
    'class':'Sinif',
    'subject':'Fənnin adını daxil edin',
    'dob': 'Date of Birth'
};
$('input').live('focus', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.hasClass('default')) {
        el.removeClass('default').val('');
    }
    if (el.attr('id') === 'dob') {
        $(this).mask('99.99.9999', {placeholder:' '});
    }
});

$('input').live('blur', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var name = el.attr('name');

    // Really we only want to do anything if the field is *empty*
    if (el.val().match(/^[\s\.]*$/)) {

        // To get our default style back, we'll re-add the classname
        el.addClass('default');

        // Unmask the 'dob' field
        if (name == 'dob') {
            el.unmask();
        }

        // And finally repopulate the field with its default value
        el.val(defaultValues[name]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should definitely also be validating on the server, too, in addition to any client-side validation that occurs. Client-side validation is inherently weak.

Comment: it will extra load for serverside. Why do i need serverside validation if this way is possible?

Comment: Because you're handing your validation over to the client, which can be easily manipulated. DO NOT RELY ON THIS ONLY. All caps because this is important to understand.

Comment: ok, i will do it in serverside to, but at first, can you help me to finish client side?

Comment: What you're looking for is that when the form is submitted, when `onSubmit` fires you check each field to see if it matches the default value? Or that it doesn't? I'm not sure what kind of behavior you're looking for. Usually default values are caught and the form submit is canceled with an error to the user. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. If the values are default (user doesn't change anything and only pressed submit button) or fields are empty then cancel submit. And of course i want to check for email validity and date of birth. date of birth looks like 09.06.2010 (dots and digits) I want alert about errors and unfilled fields

Comment: Sorry Tural, I'm going to be gone for a while. I'll check in on this later.

Comment: anyway, thank for trying to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think you should add an `id` to each form element. I don't think jQuery will grab a DOM element with its `name`. Your form has an id but not your input elements.

So for example, see the input element below (the id can be same as the name):

```
<input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="Adınız"  />
```

Now you can grab that element via jQuery like this: `alert($('#pwd').val());`

The `#` before `pwd` indicates that the element is being selected by its id.
You could also select an element by referecing its class like this: `alert($('.className').val());` but this will select all matching elements with the same class applied to them. To make a single and specific select; you should use ids.

So, if I understand your question right; you can validate the value of these elements by checking whether they have the default value or if they are empty first. Then checking other criterias such as password length, etc..

```
    $('#reg').submit(function (event) 
    {
        if ($('#pwd').val() == defaultValues['pwd'] || $.trim($('#pwd').val()) == '')
        {
            alert('Please enter a password!');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($('#pwd').val().length < 8)
            {
                alert('Password must have 8 characters at least!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Note: I agree with Jared. You should validate this form on the server-side too; since the code is visible in the browser and can easily be by-passed.

Comment: What i need to do at the end of this js? Lets say we wrote if's for all possible cases. What if allright and we want to continue submitting process? Do i need to write new if for it and end this if with "return true?" @Onur, skaypla konusa bilirmiyiz? skayp id: tural.teyyuboglu Tesekkurler

Comment: I used this piece of code but it always gives me the same error message "Please enter a password!" even if all input fields are filled. How can we modify this code to alert the array of errors? for example if my pass is wrong type and name field unfilled the show 2 errors at once. I thought about logic too: For example every time when some case is true then it pushes to array the error message and when it finishes checking all cases, shows the error array

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill in a way, but I wanted to demonstrate a few different things here. Primarily:

- Namespacing event handlers
- Custom event handling
- Triggering event handlers
- Error detection and handling with an array of errors
- Using attributes and `$.data()` to store your element-related data
- Using a structured object to configure your form

Read through the comments and let me know if you have any questions.

**Mock HTML**

```
<form id="reg" method="post" action="core/code/functions/signup.php">
<table width="270px" style="clear:both">
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px">Əsas məlumatlar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="fname" value=""/></td>
 <td><input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="mname" value=""/></td>
 <td><input class="part1 default" type="text" name="lname" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px">
     Password: <input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="pwd"/>
 </td>
<tr>
</tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px">
     DOB: <input class="part1 default required" type="text" name="dob"/>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px">
     Phone: <input class="part1 default" type="text" name="phone"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input class="button button-gray"  type="submit" value="Tamam" name="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
// An object containing different fields by name and
// objects that provide information about the object the
// name points to. 'default' property is required.
var defaultValues = {
    'fname': {'default':'Adınız'},
    'mname': {'default':'Atanızın adı'},
    'lname': {'default':'Soyadınız'},
    'phone': {'default':'Telefon'},
    'email': {'default':'Email'},
    'pwd': {
        'default':'Şifrə',
        // Text used to display a custom error text.
        // Otherwise, the default text will be used.
        'errortext':'Password must be 5 characters or more in length',
        // A custom function to be called when the element is validated
        // and/or checked for default. This is added as a custom event
        // handler called 'validation' and called on blur.checkRequired
        // and from the function checkRequired() when the
        // blur.checkRequired is triggered. The 'notvalidated' data
        // element is how the validation failure is passed back to
        // blur.checkDefault event.
        'onvalidation': function(){
            if (this.value.length < 5) {
                $(this).data('notvalidated',true);
            } else {
                $(this).data('notvalidated',false);
            }
        }
    },
    'region': {'default':'Rayon'},
    'school': {'default':'Məktəb'},
    'login': {'default':'Istifadəçi adı'},
    'class': {'default':'Sinif'},
    'subject': {'default':'Fənnin adını daxil edin'},
    'dob': {
        'default':'Date of Birth',
        // An alternate value to check for, in addition to
        // the default. More complex checks should be checked
        // through the onvalidation handler.
        'validate':'  .  .    ',
        'errortext':'A correct Date of Birth must be entered.'
    }
};
function checkRequired() {
    // We will attach the error list to the body tag.
    var $body = $('body');
    // This array will store the actual errors, but this specfically
    // clears previous errors caught.
    $body.data('requiredErrors',[]);
    $('input.required').each(function(){
        // Trigger is used to manually call the blur.checkRequired
        // handler.
        $(this).trigger('blur.checkRequired');
    });
    // Get a reference to the errors generated by the triggered
    // event handler.
    var errors = $body.data('requiredErrors');
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // This will allow you output an error to the user.
        var errortext = "There were "+errors.length+" errors "+
            "submitting the form.<br/>"+
            "These errors must be fixed before submitting the form."+
            "<ul>";
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            errortext += "<li>"+errors[i]+"</li>";
        }
        errortext += '</ul>';
        errortext = '<div id="requiredErrorsText">'+errortext+'</div>';
        // First try to remove it if it's already showing.
        $('#requiredErrorsText').remove();
        // At it to the top of the form.
        $(errortext).prependTo('form');
        // Return false to the submit event handler to prevent the form
        // from submitting.
        return false;
    }
    // Return true to allow the form to continue submitting.
    return true;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the initial errors log array.
    $('body').data('requiredErrors',[]);
    // Loop through and apply the defaultValues object information
    // to the related elements.
    for (var name in defaultValues) {
        // Name is the key object reference and should point to an
        // input element with the name attribute equal to it.
        var $this = $('input[name="'+name+'"]');
        var validate = '';
        var errortext = '';
        // Only do the apply if their are elements found.
        if ($this.length != 0) {
            // Add the custom or default value to validate against.
            // If both are available, it will check both during the
            // blur.checkRequired handler.
            if (defaultValues[name].hasOwnProperty('validate')) {
                validate = defaultValues[name].validate;
            } else {
                validate = defaultValues[name].default;
            }
            // Set the value for the error text to display, defaulting
            // to the 'default' value if the property does not exist.
            if (defaultValues[name].hasOwnProperty('errortext')) {
                errortext = defaultValues[name].errortext;
            } else {
                errortext = defaultValues[name].default;
            }
            // Add the validation event handler, if present.
            if (typeof defaultValues[name].onvalidation == 'function') {
                $this.bind('validation',defaultValues[name].onvalidation);
                // Tell the blur.checkRequired() to run the validator handler.
                $this.data('usevalidator',true);
            } else {
                $this.data('usevalidator',false);
            }
            // Set the default value to the... default value if it is present
            // and the element's value is empty. Note, this will allow you to
            // not overwrite values returned by a roundtrip to the server
            // (in case the submit handler does not prevent the form being
            // being submitted.
            if ($this.val() == '' && defaultValues[name].default) {
                $this.val(defaultValues[name].default);
            }
            // Set custom attributes for the related values.
            $this.attr('default',defaultValues[name].default);
            $this.attr('validate',validate);
            $this.attr('errortext',errortext);
        }
    }
    $('form').submit(function(){
        // NOTE!!! I am return false to prevent the form in jsfiddle
        // from submitting the form EVER. This is just for diagnostic
        // reasons, it should not done in your production script.
        if (checkRequired()) {
            alert('Form will submit.');
        } else {
            alert('Form will NOT submit');
            return false;
        }
        // Remove this when you want to use this for real.
        return false;
    });
    // We will use a cached jQuery object.
    $default = $('input[type="text"][default],input[type="text"].required');
    // See http://api.jquery.com/bind/ for more on custom events,
    // including namespaced events like blur.checkRequired.
    $default.live('blur.checkRequired',function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $body = $('body');
        var notvalidated = true;
        // Having the 'required' class on the input causes it to
        // check for validation.
        if ($this.hasClass('required')) {
            // Triggers the custom validation handler.
            if ($this.data('usevalidator') === true) {
                $this.trigger('validation');
            }
            notvalidated = $this.val() == '' ||
                           $this.val() == $this.attr('default') ||
                           $this.val() == $this.attr('validate') ||
                           $this.data('notvalidated') === true;
            if (notvalidated) {
                $body.data('requiredErrors').push($this.attr('errortext'));
                $this.addClass('requiredError');
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('requiredError');
            }
        }
    });
    // Namespaced handlers prepended with a regular handler like
    // blur, focus, etc... will be fired with the regular handler.
    $default.live('focus.checkDefault', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.hasClass('default')) {
            el.removeClass('default').val('');
        }
        if (el.attr('name') === 'dob') {
            $(this).mask('99.99.9999', {placeholder:' '});
        }
    });
    $default.live('blur.checkDefault', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var name = el.attr('name');

        // Really we only want to do anything if the field is *empty*
        if (el.val().match(/^[\s\.]*$/)) {

            // To get our default style back, we'll re-add the classname
            el.addClass('default');

            // Unmask the 'dob' field
            if (name == 'dob') {
                el.unmask();
            }

            // And finally repopulate the field with its default value
            el.val(el.attr('default'));
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CMmDF/